# Reading a xap file from webclient

Tags: silverlight, webclient, xap

I have hosted my silverlight service on the server. I have created a client application on my local machine referencing the silverlight service on the server. Everything compiles and work fine.

Now I coped the xap file into another silverlight application and tried to read the xap using the following code.

```
     StreamResourceInfo _streamResourceInfo = new StreamResourceInfo(e.Result, null);
        StreamResourceInfo _streamResourceInfoDll = Application.GetResourceStream(_streamResourceInfo,
                                          new Uri(string.Format("{0}.dll", abc), UriKind.Relative));
        AssemblyPart _assemblyPart = new AssemblyPart();
        Assembly _assembly = _assemblyPart.Load(_streamResourceInfoDll.Stream);
        UserControl _userControl = _assembly.CreateInstance(string.Format("{0}.MainPage", abc)) as UserControl;
        this.Main_Canvas.Children.Add(_userControl);
```

Everything works fine. Now I added Navigation Framework to my application.

I modified the main page with navigation framework. In my main page I have

```
     <navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Source="/Views/abc.xaml" Grid.Row="1" >
```

When I Copy the modified xap on to the other application. It complains  No xaml is found at the location /Views/abc.xaml.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer is pretty comprehensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360993/mef-silverlight-how-do-i-navigate-to-a-page-in-another-xap)

But... if dynamic XAP loading is your thing, do yourself a favour and take a look at [Jounce](http://jounce.codeplex.com/) - It's an MVVM framework, but that doesn't mean you absolutely must use ViewModels.

Comment: Thanks TriggerPin, Sorry for the late reply. Will definitely look into it.